# How to get next cell with alphabet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I read [openpyxl - Reading a next cell value in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581842/openpyxl-reading-a-next-cell-value-in-a-loop).
There was no appropriate answer.

I am searching an random cell.

In the case I get value from "AB1", my target is "AC1".

If it's "sheet.cell(row=1, column=1)", I can increment it like

```
sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
```

However, its alphabet.

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: If you are using openpyxl or pandas, it sees them as numbers and not characters representing numbers.

Comment: Thank you anand. 
Then, is there anyway to get right next cell's value?

Comment: If I am right, you have an excel sheet, you are searching if a value exists, and if it does, you want to extract the value in the column on it's right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. kind of you, I found the answer. I am going to post.

Comment: Use `cell.offset(…)`

Comment: omg why right answer always come after I find an another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to helps.

```
# colnum="AZ", rownum="9"
alink = sh[colnum+rownum].value
```

In this case,

```
# colnum="AZ", colint="52"
colint = openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string(colnum)

nextcell = sh.cell(row=i, column=colint+1).value
```

Then, I could get next cell!